# How to split a string to to merge the repeat items together in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, split, repeat

How to split a string in the following way:

```
a = "111554222117"
```

My goal is to split string into several pieces, where the continuous repeated will grouped together.  The output will be a list

```
b = ['111','55','4','222','11','7']
```

PS: not tool can be used like `itertools` since this is an interview question.

My attempt is to use at least two `for` loop, but it is not effective. how to use only one `loop`.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try anything to solve it?

Comment: This looks like a coding problem... What have you tried already?

Comment: This is pretty easy to do with a normal `for` loop.

Comment: If you don't want to use the standard library, please post your attempt and explain where exactly you're stuck.

Comment: "My attempt is to use at least for loop, but it is not effective" - please post your _code_ that attempts to solve this and explain how exactly it doesn't work. If your code works, you're looking for [codereview.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> [''.join(data) for _, data in itertools.groupby("111554222117")]
['111', '55', '4', '222', '11', '7']
```

Comment: Thanks for all your feedback, is it possible to not use `itertools` to solve the problem?   I search for an elegant solution,

Comment: @Jason, please provide _your own_ solution first and explain how exactly it doesn't work. If it does, then you'd better post at [codereview.se].

Comment: @ForceBru, thanks for the hint. I now know there is a `Code Review`.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = "111554222117"
b = []
s = a[0]
for i in range(1,len(a)):
    if a[i] == s[0]:
        s += a[i]
    else:
        b.append(s)
        s = a[i]
b.append(s)
```